# Please reopen this question

Tags: discussion

Off topic, guys? Seriously?

[Accessing another process virtual memory in Linux (debugging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919225/accessing-another-process-virtual-memory-in-linux-debugging)

especially when the answer is exactly what I was looking for

> How does gdb access another process virtual memory on Linux? Is it all
>   done via /proc?
>
> It call lots of times ptrace system call with
>   PTRACE_PEEKTEX/PTRACE_PEEKDATA to read data and with PTRACE_POKETEXT,
>   PTRACE_POKEDATA to write data .
>
> From man:
>
> PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, PTRACE_PEEKDATA
>
> Read a word at the address addr in the tracee's memory, returning the
>   word as the result of the ptrace() call. Linux does not have separate
>   text and data address spaces, so these two requests are currently
>   equivalent. (data is ignored.)
>
> and
>
> PTRACE_POKETEXT, PTRACE_POKEDATA
>
> Copy the word data to the address addr in the tracee's memory. As for
>   PTRACE_PEEKTEXT and PTRACE_PEEKDATA, these two requests are currently
>   equivalent.
>
> As for:
>
> where can I find information about ... setting hardware watchpoints
>
> gdb, Internals Watchpoint:s
>   http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/Internals%20Watchpoints
>
> Reference:
>
> http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace
>   http://www.alexonlinux.com/how-debugger-works

Comment: The close reason is rather clear - you are asking for external resources, documentation. So, yes this is off-topic.

Comment: @oded: how about now then

Comment: @oded: you know, you are lucky that you are basically the only place where one can ask questions and get answers, because otherwise I would have left long ago.

Comment: Looks overly broad now. Is there something _specific_ you need to do? If you are looking for general understanding - it may very well be unsuitable for [so].

Comment: @oded: I want to know how to access the virtual memory of another process. Is that too hard? should I go to reddit?

Comment: All I can say - we are strict for a reason. And being strict is *why* we are the place where you can ask questions and get answers.

Comment: "I need to access the virtual memory of another process. Here is what I tried..."

Comment: Name calling? Really?

Comment: @oded: I can't try something if I don't even know the keywords to search for.

Comment: I appreciate that and I appreciate that you are frustrated - it has been a long time since I've even tried to ask a question on [so]. And it is difficult to ask a good one, in particular if the issue is vague in ones mind.

Comment: @oded: This is nonsense. The answer provided responds exactly to my specific question.

Comment: What answer? Has it been deleted now?

Comment: @Tanner: the answer is deleted, and I can only see it because of 10k. Excuse me if I am trying to enrich the site. and it was probably deleted because someone with too much time on their hands had the interesting idea to close it as offtopic just because, in the meantime, I asked for qualifying links to the answer.

Comment: @Tanner - the answer poster deleted it. I don't know why.

Comment: @oded: probably because since it was closed, he decided it wasn't worth leaving it there.

Comment: I am not a mind reader and will not assume I know what went through their head.

Comment: @oded and since I am not a mind reader, I cannot expect to marry the feeling of five guys that happened to pass by and throw a close vote just because they don't understand what I am asking.

Comment: Hooooooooooold up folks. Give me a moment to take this in, okay? This is getting way out of hand and I don't want to lock it while I get up to speed - but will. _If_ something was done incorrectly here, I'll fix it, and address it, but I need a few minutes to dig in.

Comment: [Status-Completed]

Comment: @Oded - overriding the answerer's decision is troublesome.  At least anonymize the owner of the post so he isn't stuck having to support it.

Comment: @Hans - I'll let the answer OP make that call.

Comment: @Oded - he can't do it himself, he can only delete it again.

Comment: @Hans - which is why I left a comment for the answer OP to let me know if that's what they wish (and since it is now an accepted answer, they can't delete it either)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know what, I don't think the original incarnation of your question was at all out of line. It was a bit broad, but if you had phrased it like:

> Is there some guideline to follow to help figure out if I should be wading through kernel source, glib documentation or perhaps something else based on what I'm trying to accomplish? Debugging, tracing and setting hardware watch points can lead you down a variety of paths, when it comes to getting the documentation that one needs. Is there some way to know which way to go?

Or, more simply:

> I'm going to be going down the rabbit hole of debugging, tracing and setting hardware watch points - and there's a *lot* of irrelevant stuff coming up in searches. What should I have at the ready, to consult - ideally without wasting a lot of time just to find that it wasn't what I really needed?

Essentially the same thing, and links would probably constitute a helpful answer, but you're asking for more *knowledge* there than someone's recollection that something exists somewhere - that's what people were reacting to, and what I don't think anyone has managed to articulate in response to your post here.

Questions that *purely*, or mostly ask "Where can I read about [x]" really don't fit our model well. But, you had an actual question there.

Now ...

People, you need to ***stop closing stuff based on trigger words and try to figure out the intent of the question before voting to close it.*** There was a perfectly *valid* question in the first paragraph of the post. You skipped that, found something wrong with something else tossed in, and shut down the whole post. Thank *zod* Homer didn't ask for directions to the latrine at the end of the Iliad, just sayin'

Comment: My hope for an answer was "the routine is ptrace, and it's part of the "whatever-DTrace-is-called-on-linux" framework.

Comment: @StefanoBorini exactly, it would have been rather difficult for you to be much more specific without knowing the answer in advance, which .. well.. rather obviates the question if that were the case :)

Answer (score 2):

Part of your question:

> More generally, where can I find information about the Linux API for debugging/tracing/setting hardware watchpoints and so on?

Close reason:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic

Looks like it was closed correctly.

---

Your updated question now reads

> How does gdb access another process virtual memory on Linux? Is it all done via /proc?

so that close reason no longer applies. I guess it could be reopened but I don't know about the subject so I can't judge if it's too broad or not, so I'll leave it to others.

Comment: Ok so asking to motivate the answer to your question with a more general link is now off topic? I mean guys, did you all have crazy pills this morning?

Comment: This "too broad" thing is also obnoxious. How can I know if something is too broad, requiring tens of calls, or if it's just a single syscall _before_ asking the question?

Comment: Especially considering that the answer of the question precisely answers the question I asked.

Comment: @StefanoBorini Fair enough, I'll vote to reopen. But you do understand the reason your original question was closed? It's fine to disagree with policies of course, but this is how such questions are currently handled.

Comment: no, I don't understand it because it's stupid that someone would consider a request for contextualisation of their answer as a motivation for off topic.